# Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'

Tags: swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, autorest

I am getting this error after upgrading my api from .netcore2.2 to 3.1 and trying to generate using autorest with the --v3 switch

> WARNING: Schema violation: Data does not match any schemas from
> 'oneOf'

I have tried with and without  SerializeAsV2

I see from [the Autorest docs](https://github.com/Azure/AutoRest#:%7E:text=AutoRest%203.0%20finally%20supports%20OpenAPI3%20files%20as%20an,OpenAPI3%20specific%20features%20may%20not%20be%20entirely%20supported) that this warning is because of an supported feature.

> anyOf, oneOf are not currently supported

In services.AddSwaggerGen I have

```
            c.ParameterFilter<SwaggerEnumParameterFilter>();
            c.SchemaFilter<SwaggerEnumFilter>();
```

where

```
public void Apply(OpenApiParameter parameter, ParameterFilterContext context)
{
    var type = context.ApiParameterDescription.Type;

    if (type.IsEnum)
        parameter.Extensions.Add("x-ms-enum", new OpenApiObject
        {
            ["name"] = new OpenApiString(type.Name),
            ["modelAsString"] = new OpenApiBoolean(false)
        });
     
}

public class SwaggerEnumFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (model == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        if (context.Type.IsEnum)
            model.Extensions.Add(
                "x-ms-enum",
                new OpenApiObject
                {
                    ["name"] = new OpenApiString(context.Type.Name),
                    ["modelAsString"] = new OpenApiBoolean(false)
                }
            );
    }
}
```

[update]

After upgrading to Autorest 3.0.6244 the warnings have changed to errors and the error message ends with

```
post > parameters > 0)
```

If I don't use the v3 switch I get the error

```
FATAL: swagger-document/individual/schema-validator - FAILED
FATAL: Error: [OperationAbortedException] Error occurred. Exiting.
Process() cancelled due to exception : [OperationAbortedException] Error occurred. Exiting.
```

I can see in the swagger.json that the parameters property "name" is not generating correctly. Here it contains "body" whereas previously it contained "info"

```
"/api/FrameLookUp": {
    "post": {
        "tags": [
            "Frame"
        ],
        "operationId": "FrameLookup",
        "consumes": [
            "application/json-patch+json",
            "application/json",
            "text/json",
            "application/*+json"
        ],
        "produces": [
            "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "in": "header",
                "name": "Authorization",
                "description": "access token",
                "required": true,
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "in": "body", 
                "name": "body",
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/FrameRequest"
                }
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "Success",
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/FrameResponse"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

The controller is

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api")]

public class FrameController : MyController
{
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(FrameResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [HttpPost("FrameLookUp")]
    public IActionResult FrameLookup([FromBody] FrameRequest  info)
    {
        IMyResponse MyFunc(IMyRequest x) => FrameData.FrameLookUp(info);
        return InnerMethod(MyFunc, info);
    }
 }
```

Update

I have also tried using the SwaggerParameter from Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations

[Update]

I am thinking that maybe I just need to try the release for issue 1766

I tried cloning the swashbuckle.aspnetcore repo but ran into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858266/ts6053building-swashbuckle-aspnetcore)

[Update]

I added c.GeneratePolymorphicSchemas(); to the AddSwaggerGen options but it has not helped.

[Update]
Here is the first error message

```
ERROR: Schema violation: Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'
    - https://localhost:44348/api-docs/v1/swagger.json:1951:8 ($.paths["/api/synchronise-management/get-product-images-Ids"].post.parameters)
```

Investigating line 1951 in swagger.json

[image: line which causes error]

In the working swagger ( generated from dotnet2.2 project ) the json looks very similar however the parameter order is swapped
[image: working json]

The other difference I can see is the generated name of the parameter

I see from [this question](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/3305) the error occurs in the same place

[Update]
when I add the --debug switch to the autorest call I get

```
/configuration
DEBUG: pipeline-emitter - END
DEBUG: configuration-emitter - END
DEBUG: swagger-document-override/md-override-loader - END
DEBUG: swagger-document/loader - END
DEBUG: swagger-document/individual/transform - START
DEBUG: swagger-document/individual/transform - END
DEBUG: swagger-document/individual/schema-validator - START
ERROR: Schema violation: Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'
    - https://localhost:44348/api/v1/swagger.json:1951:8 ($.paths["/api/synchronise-management/get-product-images-Ids"].
```

[Update]

Here is the cut down json

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "myapi API31",
        "description": "ASP.NET Core Web API",
        "version": "v1"
    },
    "host": "localhost:44348",
    "basePath": "/v1",
    "schemes": [
        "https"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/api/Test": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "Auth"
                ],
                "operationId": "Test",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/api/RequestToken": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "Auth"
                ],
                "operationId": "RequestToken",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json-patch+json",
                    "application/json",
                    "text/json",
                    "application/*+json"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "in": "body",
                        "name": "body",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/TokenRequest"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/TokenResponse"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/api/FrameLookUp": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "Frame"
                ],
                "operationId": "FrameLookup",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json-patch+json",
                    "application/json",
                    "text/json",
                    "application/*+json"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "in": "header",
                        "name": "Authorization",
                        "description": "access token",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    {
                        "in": "body",
                        "name": "body",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/FrameRequest"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/FrameResponse"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    },
    "definitions": {
        "TokenRequest": {
            "required": [
                "password",
                "username"
            ],
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "username": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "password": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "TokenResponse": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "tokenResult": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "FramePackTypeEnum": {
            "enum": [
                "NotApplicable",
                "PipeRack",
                "LwBVan",
                "VanTray",
                "Car",
                "CarryBag"
            ],
            "type": "string",
            "x-ms-enum": {
                "name": "FramePackTypeEnum",
                "modelAsString": false
            }
        },
        "FrameRequest": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "qCodeJobId": {
                    "format": "int32",
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "quantity": {
                    "format": "int32",
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "widthInMm": {
                    "format": "int32",
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "heightInMm": {
                    "format": "int32",
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "ePackingType": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/FramePackTypeEnum"
                },
                "userEmail": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "FrameCaseEnum": {
            "enum": [
                "Case0_NoBraces",
                "Case1_1Vertical_0Horizontal",
                "Case2_2Vertical_0Horizontal",
                "Case3_NVertical_0Horizontal",
                "Case4_0Vertical_1Horizontal",
                "Case5_1Vertical_1Horizontal",
                "Case6_2Vertical_1Horizontal",
                "Case7_NVertical_1Horizontal",
                "Case8_0Vertical_2Horizontal",
                "Case9_1Vertical_2Horizontal",
                "Case10_2Vertical_2Horizontal",
                "Case11_NVertical_2Horizontal",
                "Case12_0Vertical_NHorizontal",
                "Case13_1Vertical_NHorizontal",
                "Case14_2Vertical_NHorizontal",
                "Case15_NVertical_NHorizontal"
            ],
            "type": "string",
            "x-ms-enum": {
                "name": "FrameCaseEnum",
                "modelAsString": false
            }
        },
        "FrameResponse": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "caseNumber": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/FrameCaseEnum"
                },
                "memberPriceEachExGst": {
                    "format": "double",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "retailPriceEachExGst": {
                    "format": "double",
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the .netcore2.2 api the request generates as

```
"FrameRequest": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "qCodeJobId": {
            "format": "int32",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "quantity": {
            "format": "int32",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "widthInMm": {
            "format": "int32",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "heightInMm": {
            "format": "int32",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "ePackingType": {
            "enum": [
                "NotApplicable",
                "PipeRack",
                "LwBVan",
                "VanTray",
                "Car",
                "CarryBag"
            ],
            "type": "string",
            "x-ms-enum": {
                "name": "FramePackTypeEnum",
                "modelAsString": false
            }
        },
        "userEmail": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the command line I am running

```
autorest --input-file=.\myswagger.json --output-folder=generated --csharp --namespace=DDD --debug
```

---

Some links which the author, Kirsten Greed, put in comments:

- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#schema-filters
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/1766
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63857310/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-d-dev-swashbuckle-aspnetcore-src-swashbuckle

Comment: Can you post your `swagger.json` that causes this issue

Comment: Thankyou @HelderSepulveda how do I find out the line?

Comment: find out the line?!?! Not sure what you mean ... Can you post your entire  swagger.json or a link to it

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the line info. Sorry but I can't post all the .json

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the line you point to ... If you can not post all the json can you create one that reproduces your issue and post it here

Comment: Thanks. I realised I could just trim it down. I updated the question.

Comment: your trim down version is missing stuff where is the `"$ref": "#/definitions/FrameRequest"`  that does not pass validation: https://validator.swagger.io/validator/debug?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/swagger/63783800_swagger.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221403/discussion-between-kirsten-greed-and-helder-sepulveda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your swagger.json we can see the validation shows:
https://validator.swagger.io/validator/debug?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/swagger/63783800_swagger.json

```
{
"schemaValidationMessages": [
{
  "level": "error",
  "domain": "validation",
  "keyword": "oneOf",
  "message": "instance failed to match exactly one schema (matched 0 out of 2)",
  "schema": {
    "loadingURI": "http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#",
    "pointer": "/definitions/parametersList/items"
  },
  "instance": {
    "pointer": "/paths/~1api~1FrameLookUp/post/parameters/0"
  }
}
]
}
```

that lead us to your code:

[image]

that `type: "String"` should be: `type: "string"` with all lower case the error goes away

Comment: Thank you so much! A followup issue is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63866746/swagger-json-generating-with-incorrect-case-type-string

Comment: And showing me validator.swagger.io with the POST /debug