# TS6053 Building Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Tags: swashbuckle.aspnetcore, redoc

I cloned Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and am trying to build it
However the node_modules folder is missing

[image: node modules]

I ran [npm i redoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redoc) and got the following output

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\System32\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\System32\package.json'
npm WARN redoc@2.0.0-rc.40 requires a peer of mobx@^4.2.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redoc@2.0.0-rc.40 requires a peer of react@^16.8.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redoc@2.0.0-rc.40 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redoc@2.0.0-rc.40 requires a peer of styled-components@^4.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mobx-react@6.3.0 requires a peer of mobx@^5.15.4 || ^4.15.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mobx-react@6.3.0 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 16.9.0-alpha.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-tabs@3.1.1 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @redocly/react-dropdown-aria@2.0.11 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @redocly/react-dropdown-aria@2.0.11 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @redocly/react-dropdown-aria@2.0.11 requires a peer of styled-components@^5.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mobx-react-lite@2.2.1 requires a peer of mobx@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mobx-react-lite@2.2.1 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN System32 No description
npm WARN System32 No repository field.
npm WARN System32 No README data
npm WARN System32 No license field.
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895493/solving-the-npm-warn-saveerror-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-users

Answer (score 0):

I needed to be in the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.ReDoc folder before running the command

```
npm i redoc
```